# Windows 8.1 Installation Woes - EV Certs and Elevated Privileges

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, windows-8.1

I've just had to jump through hoops to get my application to install on Windows 8.1 and I'm concerned for my users.  I'm testing the installer inside Parallels on my macbook.

First of all I had to disable SmartScreen as this just completely borked everything and wouldn't allow the installer to run at all.  I'm not really happy to just tell my users to turn this off as that doesn't really make much sense.

After I jumped through that hoop Windows wouldn't allow my installer to access the C:\Program Files(x86)\ directory without administration rights.  I have only one user on the machine that is in the administrators group and I was running the installer through that account.

There also wasn't a `Run as Admin` option in the context menu so I had to open a Command Prompt as Administrator and issue the following command:

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

Then reboot the machine.

Since I'm a one man band operation making a free app I'm seriously short on beta testers and I can't justify getting an EV certificate to sign the installer with etc.

Seems making / distributing apps for Windows is getting harder and also trashing the user experience in the process.

What are the real options to make things better for my users?

The installer technology is WiX and I already set the following in the installer:

```
<Property Id="MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION" Value="1" />
```

In the Product element I also already set the following:

```
InstallScope="perMachine"
InstallPrivileges="elevated"
```

Comment: Have you tried taking out the 'MSIUSEREALADMINDETECTION' and InstallPrivileges="elevated" and just use the perMachine InstallScope? The installer should elevate at the appropriate time without those.

Comment: I added that line as I was having issues on 8.1 so I doubt removing it is going to help.